# How customize text inserted when "now" button is clicked in a jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

Using datetime picker I let user to select time that is going to be set remotely on a linux server.

**Q1:** When clicking now button I want this text *"sntp -P no -r pool.ntp.org"* to appear in the text box. Is that possible?

**Q2:** Or how to add another button that would insert text **"sntp -P no -r pool.ntp.org"** inside datepicker text box?

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/dPRjS/8/)

Answer (score 2):

you can do some thing like this to achieve.

[How to add some custom text to the DatePicker’s text field?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-add-some-custom-text-to-the-datepickers-text-field/)

here, you must override the default val method, to remove the custom string in the datapicker
removing the string will help you to highlight the previously selected date in calender. because the datepicker use the val function to know which date is selected to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I once found that adds a "clear" button. It shouldn't be hard to replace it with the button you need;

http://jsbin.com/ofare/edit#javascript,html

Note that I didn't make this myself, I just found it and use it myself.
I don't like how it requires a timeout() though, so I'll be keeping an eye on this thread if a better solution is found :)